# Is the paladin's Divine Sanction an immediate interrupt, op. attack or what?

Tags: dnd-4e, paladin

The entry to the paladin's Divine Sanction mentions that an enemy takes damage the first time it makes an attack that does not include you (the paladin) as a target.

Normally it's not a huge issue (he's taking damage at some point, hooray!) but this scenario came up the other day. Say an enemy is sanctioned. He makes an attack against the party member. This activates the divine sanction and the monster takes retributive damage and would die from this retributive damage.

However since divine sanction doesn't state it's an immediate interrupt or anything, does the enemy attack still damage the party member if it's attack hit succesfully? Or is the enemy struck down before it could get the damage off?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to a previous entry in the Wizards [PHB FAQ](http://wizards.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/wizards.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=1396), the enemy attack would damage the party member before it died to the Divine Sanction damage:

> **40. When does the damage from divine challenge occur? If it’s enough to kill the monster making the attack does his attack still happen?**
>
> Yes. The damage is in response to the
>   marked creature's attack; the damage
>   is not an interrupt. In general,
>   effects are not interrupts unless they
>   are designated as such or unless they
>   would be otherwise nonfunctional.

At the time this was written, Divine Challenge and Divine Sanction worked identically.  In November 2010, [Divine Challenge was issued errata](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/Nov2010Update.pdf).

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you sir, I seemed to have missed that entry while looking for answers.